# Why does the example with two echo statements output a table instead of the expected string?

Tags: org-babel

In the second example of the code snippet I am expecting

```
foo are you
I am emacs
```

but get a table instead. What sort of commands or options are required to get the expected output. What is the significance of the colon in the first results line? I suspect it is of some relevance.

```lisp
#+TITLE: Test Use of :var across multiple lines

#+begin_src sh :var x="foo" :var y=" are you?" :var z="I am Emacs"
echo $x $y
# echo $z
#+end_src

#+RESULTS:
: foo are you?


#+begin_src sh :var x="foo" :var y=" are you?" :var z="I am Emacs"
echo $x $y
echo $z
#+end_src

#+RESULTS:
| foo | are | you?  |
| I   | am  | Emacs |
```

Comment: The colon means "print text verbatim", usually, using monospace font. The table is due to the result being a list. In a moment, I'll write something up to print result as just text.

Comment: As a shell programming caveat, you should quote the variables unless you specifically want the shell to perform whitespace tokenization and wildcard expansion on the values.  To wit, `$y` will be expanded to a list of matching filenames if you have any files whose names match the wildcard expression `" are you?"` (and nothing if you have the `nullglob` option set).  So `echo "$x $y"` is most probably what you actually want here.  The difference may seem small here, but it bites you when you least expect it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to specify `:results raw` if you want the echo'ed text to appear as is. Notice, this is also sometimes referred to as `:results org`, implying that the result will be interpreted as Org mode markup.

```
#+begin_src sh :var x="foo" :var y=" are you?" :var z="I am Emacs" :results raw
echo $x $y
echo $z
#+end_src

#+RESULTS:
foo are you?
I am Emacs
```

If you wanted this to produce text printed verbatim (i.e. Org mode formatting not processed), you could use `:results pp`.

```
#+begin_src sh :var x="foo" :var y=" are you?" :var z="I am Emacs" :results pp
echo $x $y
echo $z
#+end_src

#+RESULTS:
: foo are you?
: I am Emacs
```

Comment: I tried the `verbatim` option which I sounded logical, but that didn't work they way I expected